# Problems running Pandas on Python

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda

I installed anaconda with python 2.7 recently and I'm trying to run a script which uses pandas, but it doesn't work. I looked around and I haven't managed to find a solution yet. I'm running windows 10. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

```
$ python bitstamp.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bitstamp.py", line 22, in <module>
    import integrate_function
  File "C:\Users\Jinzo\Desktop\zeta_v05\integrate_function.py", line 22, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    "the C extensions first.".format(module))
ImportError: C extension: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application. not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force' to build the C extensions first.
```

Edit: I don't know what setup.py it refers to in the error message. Running this just gives

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force
C:\Python27\python.exe: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: did you try the solution in error message `python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force` ?

Comment: Did you read the error?

Comment: I don't know what setup.py it refers to. It gives -

`python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force
C:\Python27\python.exe: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: What I suggest to do is to install the Anaconda Python environment via [here](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#windows) and have a try again with your code.

Comment: Do you have another installed Python 2.7 interpreter?